# Can I use regular pins (Example: D2, A3, etc...) as serial (RX, TX)?

Tags: serial, programming, arduino-nano, power, pins

Python/Arduino Beginner here...

I have a DFplayer I am trying to hook to my Arduino and I want to hook it up through the regular pins instead of the RX and TX pins, but I've not been able to find detailed information on if I can do that and how to set it up... Is this possible to do?

Comment: https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/built-in-libraries/software-serial